# How do I test if the <head> tag contains a particular <script> tag?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a Karma spec that needs to check if the `<head>` tag contains `a <script>` tag with a particular `src`. Is that possible?

Comment: Assuming you don't need to support really old browsers (use JQuery in that case), `document.querySelectorAll('head > script[src="http://mysrc.com"]')`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
expect('head').toContainElement("script[src^='http://example.com/whatever']")
```